# <textarea> Not sending via email

Tags: php, email, textarea, message

I'm trying to create a simple email form for a client and cannot get the `<textarea>` to send as a message. I've tried everything I have found so far and nothing is working properly...
Here is my code:

```
<h4>Email Al</h4>
<table>
<form name="contactForm" id="contact" action="send_form_email.php" method="post">
    <tr>
    <td>
    <label>Name:</label>
    <input type="text" name="name">
    </td>
    <td>
    <label>Email Address:</label>
    <input type="email" name="email">
    </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
    <td colspan="2">
    <label>Website (if Available):</label>
    <input type="text" name="website">
    </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
    <td colspan="2">
    <label>Your Message:</label></br>
    <textarea for="" name="information" width="100%" rows="10" form="contactForm"></textarea>
    </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
    <td colspan="2">
    <input type="submit" value="Send Message">
    </td>
    </tr>
</form>
</table>
```

That is the form in the index.php file, below is the email send-email.php

```
<?php
  $name = $_POST['name'];
  $email = $_POST['email'];
  $website = $_POST['website'];
  $message = $_POST['information'];

    $email_from = 'myemail@gmail.com';

    $email_subject = $name . " has sent you a message!";

    $email_body = "You have received a new message from " . $name . " via your website!\n".
                            "Name:\n $name\n".
                            "Email:\n $email\n".
                            "Website:\n $website\n".
                            "Message:\n $message\n".



  $to = "clientemail@gmail.com";

  $headers = "From: $email_from \r\n";

  $headers .= "Reply-To: $visitor_email \r\n";

  mail($to,$email_subject,$email_body,$headers);


function IsInjected($str)
{
    $injections = array('(\n+)',
           '(\r+)',
           '(\t+)',
           '(%0A+)',
           '(%0D+)',
           '(%08+)',
           '(%09+)'
           );

    $inject = join('|', $injections);
    $inject = "/$inject/i";

    if(preg_match($inject,$str))
    {
      return true;
    }
    else
    {
      return false;
    }
}

if(IsInjected($visitor_email))
{
    echo "Bad email value!";
    exit;
}
?>
<?php
header("Location: /formsubmitted.php"); /* Redirect browser */
exit();
?>
```

If anyone has any clue why this is malfunctioning I would love to know as well! This is one of the first message/email php functions I've created myself as I usually develop for wordpress, so I would normally just install a plugin for my client.

Comment: "nothing is working properly" - please explain what is not working. Does it give an error?

Comment: No error. It just doesn't send that '<textarea>' . It sends every other field fine though!

Comment: Your HTML is malformed, by the way. The table should be inside the form rather than vice versa.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

That's because of this line: ***(Consult my footnote)***

```
"Message:\n $message\n".
```

You have a dot instead of a (closing) semi-colon `;`

**Edit:** You need to remove `form="contactForm"` from `<textarea>`. Upon testing, it did not show in mail when used with it.

and error reporting would have told you about it.

- http://php.net/manual/en/function.error-reporting.php

Being:

> Notice: Undefined index: information (line 8)

and

> Notice: Undefined variable: visitor_email (line 26 and 55)

In both:

```
$headers .= "Reply-To: $visitor_email \r\n";
```

and

```
if(IsInjected($visitor_email))
```

`$visitor_email` is undefined in your code. You should have used `$email` instead for all instances of `$visitor_email`.

Then you have `for=""` which doesn't appear to be valid syntax in your `<textarea...`

That `for=""` is ambiguous.

Ref: https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/HTML/Element/textarea

You should also check for empty fields with a conditional `!empty()`.

- http://php.net/manual/en/function.empty.php

---

**Footnote:**

After more intensive testing, and in regards to the dot that I mentioned above, I must state the following:

Strangely enough, PHP sees it as being valid syntax, as there is a semi-colon in and included at the end here `$to = "clientemail@gmail.com";`

What that will do is still send mail, **BUT** also include that in the email, which is clearly not included in the `$email_body` variable body.

Therefore, the first part of my answer was right to a certain extent,  the `form="contactForm"` being the major culprit here.

- You may have meant to use an ID `id="contactForm"` or a class `class="contactForm"`. Both are valid to be used and will include it in your mail.

However, you won't be able to use `name="contactForm"` since your `<form>` holds that named attribute.

- Both the `name` and `id` attributes are (meant to be) unique.

Comment: Thanks for the very fast response! I got rid of the 'for=' , which must have been a miscue from when I began to add the 'form=contactform' piece. However, adding the semi-colon rather than the dot at the end of '"Message:\n $message\n";' did not work. It still does not send the '<textarea>'

Comment: @AFick You're welcome. So, everything working? and about the dot instead of the semi-colon I noted.

Comment: I just edited my last comment! Sorry, No it still does not send. It's very odd!

Comment: @AFick Give me a minute, I'll test your code and using the closing semi-colon as noted.

Comment: Thanks so much for the help. I've been struggling with this for far too long on my own. haha

Comment: @AFick remove `form="contactForm"` from textarea. it will work. that's why

Comment: @AFick you could have waited for me, testing and writing up an answer takes time.

Comment: Thank you so much! That did it!

Comment: @AFick I made an additional edit and under **Footnote** and feel that it will be beneficial to both you and visitors to the question.

Answer (score 3):

Remove `form="contactForm"` from `<textarea>`. I removed it. And, it started working.

Replace

```
<textarea for="" name="information" width="100%" rows="10" form="contactForm"></textarea>
```

To

```
<textarea for="" name="information" width="100%" rows="10"></textarea>
```

Or,

According to **HTML5**, You can use, `form` `id's` in `input`. So, in place of `form="contactForm"` use `form="contact"`.

Change

```
<textarea for="" name="information" width="100%" rows="10" form="contactForm"></textarea>
```

To

```
<textarea for="" name="information" width="100%" rows="10" form="contact"></textarea>
```

For more info, check [textarea - attributes](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_textarea.asp)

Comment: That did it! I know I had tried it that way originally but I think a combination of taking out the 'form="contactform"' and what @Fred -ii- suggested in replacing the dot with a semicolon made it work! Thank you both!

Comment: No Problem @AFick. *Enjoy Coding*