# Html Form won't submit without input

Tags: php, html, forms

I have a form with one input, that worked. But with two inputs, none work.
I followed the W3 tutorial for submitting a textarea with the submit button but nothing happens when I press it.

I also use bootstrap, if that matters.

```
<textarea style="color: #3f3f3f; width: 40%;" rows="10" type="text" name="emailtxt" placeholder="Email Text" autocomplete="off" spellcheck="false" form="usrform"></textarea>
<form action="<?php $_SERVER['PHP_SELF'] ?>" class="form-inline" id="usrform" method="POST">
<button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">Send</button>
</form>
```

Comment: `<button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Send</button>`

Comment: ^ this is what you need ^ plus your textarea is outside form

Comment: Hey @Fred-ii- : Why we are getting today this type of questions ?

Comment: @NanaPartykar newcomers to forms I guess.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

first `textarea` is not in the form so your form is blank and you need `input type="submit` for submitting form

```
<form action="<?php echo $_SERVER['PHP_SELF'] ?>" class="form-inline" id="usrform" method="POST">
    <textarea style="color: #3f3f3f; width: 40%;" rows="10" name="emailtxt" placeholder="Email Text" autocomplete="off" spellcheck="false" form="usrform"></textarea>
    <input type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" value="Send"/>
</form>
```

Comment: `<input type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Send</button>`?

Comment: Yes! Omg, thank you! But why does it work when theres one field but not when it's one or two?

Comment: still you have only one field `textarea`.

Comment: duh, I made a mistake on `<input type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Send</button>` lol sorry

Comment: Adding to it, `<textarea>` don't have `type="text"` attribute.

Comment: Yeah, but the form (in the first place) was only submittable when you had ONE textfield but not two or zero. But now its solved so thanks!

Comment: and btw, textarea CAN be outside the form.

Comment: @user3210676 *"and btw, textarea CAN be outside the form"* - Oh sure it can, however it won't make it into PHP. ;-)

Comment: It worked just because you used `form="usrform"` in `<textarea>` @user3210676

Comment: @user3210676 as @fred-ii say you can not get the value of `textarea` then.

Comment: You can get @urfusion, because user used `form="usrform"` in `<textarea>`

Comment: @NanaPartykar:  yup. ..

Comment: @Fred-ii- I just checked and it does :) Yeah, exactly^

Comment: @NanaPartykar *Interesting*.

Comment: @user3210676 One never ceases to learn ;-) glad it all worked out. "One" meaning "myself". ;-)

Answer (score 1):

Firstly, your `<textarea>` is outside the form tags, so that won't populate when you get to the PHP part.

Sidenote edit: I stand corrected about this comment left by Nana:

> *"You can get @urfusion, because user used form="usrform" in <textarea> – Nana Partykar"*

- One always keeps on learning something new.

Then `<textarea>` does not hold `type="text"`; those are for inputs.

- https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/HTML/Element/textarea

Your button can either be

```
<button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Send</button>
```

or an input

```
<input type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" value="Send"/>
```

Now, in your PHP, you would need to assign a POST array to it.

I.e.:

```
if(isset($_POST['emailtxt'])){

$var = $_POST['emailtxt'];

}
```

or use `!empty()`.

Comment: Hey @Fred : What happened. Why you used my comment on your answer. Have i did anything wrong ? Means, i'm wrong or what. I am scared. Really. I am scared.

Comment: @NanaPartykar No, not at all. I quoted you because "I" learned something ;-) Hence the *"One always keeps on learning something new."*

Comment: *Love You Man.* You are somewhat different from others. And, thanks for quoting me.

Comment: @NanaPartykar You're welcome Nana, *cheers*

Comment: If you remember this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34829704/textarea-not-sending-via-email I edited my answer there just now.